# Unique Rule for two fields failed in Laravel

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I have this model:

```
class HrDepartment extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'hr_departments';
    protected $fillable = [
                  'company_id',
                  'dept_name',
              ];

    public function company()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Organization\OrgCompany', 'company_id');
    }
}
```

I tried to use Request Rules

Rules

```
class StoreDepartmentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        return \Gate::allows('department_create');
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'dept_name' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'min:2',
                'max:80',               
                Rule::unique('hr_departments', 'dept_name', 'company_id')
            ],

        ];
    }
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'dept_name.max:80' => 'Department Name cannot be more than 80 characters.',
            'dept_name.unique' => 'Department Name already exists.',
            'dept_name.required' => 'Please enter the Department Name.',                       
        ];
    }
}
```

Controller

```
public function store(StoreDepartmentRequest $request)
{     
        $department = HrDepartment::create([
            'dept_name'         => $request->dept_name,
            'company_id'        => Auth::user()->company_id,
        ]);
        Session::flash('success', 'Department is created successfully');
        return redirect()->route('hr.departments.index');return redirect()->route('hr.departments.index');  
    }        
}
```

I entered dept_name, Services for company 1,  when I entered Services for company 2, I got this error:

```
'Department Name already exists.',
```

Why and how do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use this code for unique validation

```
Rule::unique('hr_departments')->ignore($hr_department->id)
```